# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null on webhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I cant seem to find the problem. when i run this in Xampp it works fine, but when i transfer it to hostgator it doesnt work it says in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

here's the code:

```
 function LoadAsOwner() 
{
    Filename = document.getElementById('filename').value;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",Filename, false);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          LAO(xmlhttp);
        } 
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function LAO(xml) 
{
    var x="", i="", xmlDoc="", txt="",i="";
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("question");
    Qlength=x.length;
    QCset=new Array(Qlength);
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        QCset[i]={
            Answer: x[i].getElementsByTagName("term")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            ,Question: x[i].getElementsByTagName("detail")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            ,Selected: 0
            };
    }
    selectQuestions();
}
```

Comment: seems that `xml.responseXML` is null

Comment: what could be causing it?

Comment: what;s coming back from the request

Comment: this is suppose to be the xml http://stockknowledge8.com/Application/5.xml

Comment: I didn't ask what it is SUPPOSED to be, I asked what are you actually getting - use the *developer* tools in your browser to inspect what is being sent to it